# My field in workflow task is still required even after made it optional

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, content-type

Environment : Sharepoint Foundation 2010

A few days ago, I wanted to make my field required in a workflow task.
For that, I made required my field under the content type.
But, this had no effect. And, one day, for no apprent reason, my field became required.

Now, I just want to make it optional again. But, like before, changing its status in the content type has no effect. Then my field is still required.

I see a button in the ribbon when I configure columns from a content type, like this picture below (this is not my Sharepoint version) : **Push Changes to Sites and Lists**. This button makes nothing when I made a click.

[image: Push Changes button]

I can assure you that my field is marked as **Optional**. See ("Facultatif" means Optional in french and "Obligatoire" means Required) :

[image]

This is an example. You can see my field **AssigneA** is still required (with a little red star) :

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It works. I don't know why, but as I said, I didn't do anything and my field became optional. Then I think how I do it is the good way. Unfortunately, the changes seem to happen later for no apparent reason.